# UIRefreshControl appering in duplicated

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview, uirefreshcontrol

Anyone know why myscrollview show the UIRefreshControl in duplicated?

```
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl;
refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc]  initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTableScroll:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[_myScrollView addSubview:refreshControl];
[refreshControl setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin)];

[[refreshControl.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, refreshControl.frame.size.width, refreshControl.frame.size.height)]; //padding in Y axis
```

ImageLink-> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14600481/Untitled-1.png

Comment: are you perhaps creating this refresh control in some method that gets called multiple times? like viewWillAppear or the like?

Comment: -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews

what is the best function to init UIRefreshControl??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating this view in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, which can be called multiple times. If you wish to only have one refresh control in your view, it should be created and added to the view in `viewDidLoad` which is called only once on loading the view controller.